# Function Calls and the Stack

Tags: assembly

I'm reading this book and it says (according to this calling convention) it does this:

Note:

```
The function looks like this:
function( int a, int b)
The function call looks like this:
function(2, 1)


push arguments for function a and b backwards onto the stack
function is called, and ret is "placed" onto the stack
Prolog is executed
EBP is pushed onto stack
Variables local to the function are pushed onto the stack
```

This is how it tells me the stack looks at this point:

```
Low Memory
b
a
Ret
EBP
array
High memory
```

My questions are (since stack grows down memory addresses):

Why are a and b at the top when they are the first things pushed onto the stack? Why is array at such a high address? What does it mean "push backwards onto the stack"?

The assembly language looks like this according to the book:

```
sub 0x8, esp
sub 0x8, esp
push 0x2
push 0x1
```

Then inside the disassembled function it says:

```
push ebp
```

This is where I get really confused because 3 push commands were executed and how the hell is that gonna put ebp before a and b?

Comment: `Low Memory` and `High memory` are reversed in your diagram and the stack frame setup code is wrong. Also, this stack frame structure is totally dependent on compiler and constrained by the OS.  E.g. if you look at modern gcc stack frames, they will not work like this much of the time.  Modern Windows 64-bit frames have additional bells and whistles.  Looks like this is a poor book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No wonder you are confused, throw that book away. That said, maybe the book isn't wrong, but you misunderstand it.

You didn't say what `array` was. Assuming that's a local in the called function, the stack may look like the illustration, albeit with low and high memory mixed up.

```
High Memory
b
a
Ret
EBP (saved EBP of caller)
array (local variables of called function)
Low memory
```

Comment: The book is actually the second edition of the Shellcoder's handbook (pretty well known). I just downloaded the third edition and it's flipped like you have it.